# Getting value of variable from method to the main method

Tags: java, methods

I have this program below and I'm calling getTotalPassenger(pm) method but I'm having problems getting the value entered by the user.

```
do {
            
            /*Menu being called from method and gives 6 options to the user. 
             Chosen option will be stored in "choice" variable.*/
    
    printmenu.menu();
    
    
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    
    //Creating a switch statement for the 6 menu options.
    
    switch (choice) {
    
    
    case 1 :  /* Asks user to input total number of passengers
              and a while loop to check if a positive number input is entered.
              If a negative input is entered the user is asked again to enter a positive entry.
              All inputs are stored in a variable.
              After a positive entry program continues to next question. */
        
             getTotalPassengers(pm);
```

**The method code is :**

```
public static  int getTotolPassengers(int pm) {  
     
      while (pm <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter total number of  passengers from Malta :");
        pm = sc.nextInt();
                    
        if (pm <= 0) {
          printpositive.positive ();
          continue;
        } 
     }

    return pm;
}
```

I tried different ways like leaving it initialised as int choice = 0,

pm = 0,cm = 0,pi = 0,ci = 0,ps = 0,cs = 0, or when I tried doing it pm= getTotalPassengers(pm = 0) it works but the user is not shown the main menu printmenu.menu(); from above but the System.out.println("Enter total number of  passengers from Malta :"); from the method first and then the menu. I want to be able to use the value of the variable pm from method in the pm variable in the main method. Thanks

Comment: I have seen this question already before in a different form (now most likely deleted)... As I remember, we asked you to provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and further details. The provided code in the question is incomplete and does not run. Please edit your question to show us a minimal example...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `pm` into `getTotalPassengers()`. Define `pm` as a local integer variable and initialise to 0. Return `pm` from the function once the user has entered a valid value.

```
public static int getTotalPassengers() {
    int pm = 0;
 
    while (pm <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter total number of  passengers from Malta :");
        pm = sc.nextInt();                        
        if (pm <= 0)
            printpositive.positive();   // let user know they've entered a bad value
    }

    return pm;
}
```

Then in the `case` statement use `getTotalPassengers()`.